# Why is find returning a directory with -type f?

Tags: bash, shell, find, gnu-findutils

I'm doing some crude code analysis and I've noticed some weird error lines in my output:

```
cat: rust/library/portable-simd/crates/test_helpers: Is a directory
cat: rust/library/core/tests/iter/adapters: Is a directory
cat: rust/library/core/src/iter/adapters: Is a directory
cat: rust/library/test/src/formatters: Is a directory
cat: rust/library/test/src/helpers: Is a directory
```

Plain files are selected using `-type f` and `-print0` is used to avoid exactly this kind of error.
To make a long story short, this happens:

```
$ find rust/library/core/src/iter/adapters -print0 -type f | hexdump -C | head -n3
00000000  72 75 73 74 2f 6c 69 62  72 61 72 79 2f 63 6f 72  |rust/library/cor|
00000010  65 2f 73 72 63 2f 69 74  65 72 2f 61 64 61 70 74  |e/src/iter/adapt|
00000020  65 72 73 00 72 75 73 74  2f 6c 69 62 72 61 72 79  |ers.rust/library|
```

Note the first entry - that is a directory!

```
$ la -d rust/library/core/src/iter/adapters/
drwxr-xr-x 2 user group 4096 Apr 11 01:57 rust/library/core/src/iter/adapters/
```

To make things extra weird, the line isn't there when omitting `-print0`..

```
$ find rust/library/core/src/iter/adapters -type f | hexdump -C | head -n3
00000000  72 75 73 74 2f 6c 69 62  72 61 72 79 2f 63 6f 72  |rust/library/cor|
00000010  65 2f 73 72 63 2f 69 74  65 72 2f 61 64 61 70 74  |e/src/iter/adapt|
00000020  65 72 73 2f 6d 61 70 2e  72 73 0a 72 75 73 74 2f  |ers/map.rs.rust/|
```

Is that a bug? Looks like it - but it's find. That's like.. well, erm.. well-tested and such...
Surely, I'm using it wrong!

My find binary is from the GNU findutils package in Arch Linux.

EDIT:
This is most definitely not a bug:

```
$ podman run --rm -i -v ".:/data" --workdir /data docker.io/cicirello/gnu-on-alpine:latest find rust/library/core/src/iter/adapters -type f -print0 | hexdump -C | head -n3
00000000  72 75 73 74 2f 6c 69 62  72 61 72 79 2f 63 6f 72  |rust/library/cor|
00000010  65 2f 73 72 63 2f 69 74  65 72 2f 61 64 61 70 74  |e/src/iter/adapt|
00000020  65 72 73 2f 6d 61 70 2e  72 73 00 72 75 73 74 2f  |ers/map.rs.rust/|
```

Everything normal. Both in and out of the container, it's find 4.9.0.

Comment: Note that `find` traversal order may vary, so I think you shouldn't compare `head -n3` output.

Comment: good point! with ext4, i'm not so worried, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to swap `-print0` and `-type f`, since `-print0` causes the line to be printed.

Comment: uhh! i didn't see you response in time..
but, yeah - exactly that!

Answer (score 1):

Ok... As it so often is, it was a very small thing that determined whether those five directories were part of the output:

The order of parameters. `-print0` belongs after `-type f` - it's an action that always returns true!
The reason I only saw those directories was a `grep` for `(rs|go)$` that came later (this issue with parameter order would likely have gone unnoticed if I had included a `\.` in the regex).

The thing that reminded me that actions being expressions that can affect the results was the ominous `True;` from the man page:

```
       -print0
              True; print the full file name on the standard output,
```

And indeed, busybox find behaves the same way when the parameters are swapped.

Glorious!